# How to add a button full width after a GridLayout?

Tags: java, swing, button, layout, grid-layout

I'm working on a program that uses the button, I'm not familiar with Java Swing, and I was wondering if there is a way to add an independent button after my GridLayout (contains a certain number of rows and columns). I want to add it after the GridLayout, and takes the full width of the frame.

I tried to add it like after the GridLayout, but it changes the whole frame.
Unfortunately, I can't provide any code since I have no idea and this probably 3 or 4 lines of code.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to nest JPanels and thereby nest layouts:

- Use an outer JPanel that uses a BorderLayout
- Place the GridLayout using JPanel into the outer panel's BorderLayout.CENTER position
- Place the JButton into the outer panel's BorderLayout.PAGE_END position

Done